# Как выводить повторно компоненты и как сделать их значения уникальными?

Tags: reactjs

Добрый день. Изучаю реакт и споткнулся на такой вещи: в моей реализации есть группа инпутов, которую я выделил в 1 компонент. Они должны находиться в двух других компонентах, а ко всему прочему клонироваться столько раз, сколько будет нужно, динамически в зависимости от действий. Я делаю лифт состояний в головной компонент, но проблема в том, что: 
а) состояние привязывается сразу ко всем компонентам и меняется везде;
б) в зависимости от значений будут добавляться\удаляться эти компоненты.

Если бы делал это с JQuery, то я бы просто 2 головным компонентам(для упрощения у меня тут они не реализованы в верстке, блок CalcTable) задал бы ID, и просто считал внутри блока с этим ID кол-во ипутов(групп) и какой в ноде по счёту текущий, создал бы новый и воткнул в DOM. Событие бы висело просто на изменение любого инпута,а значения пересчитывались бы у всех сразу, менялись у текущего.

Как поступить тут не знаю, хотя бы и потому, что выводить мне нужно уже компонент, изменения его значения отражаются на всех других его клонах. То есть я не понимаю за что мне зацепиться без ID, без DOM дерева, которое как я понял тут не комильфо использовать.

Мой код этих модулей

```js
export default class InputGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(e) {
        if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
            const val = e.target.value.replace(/₽/gi, '').replace(/ /g, '');
            this.props.onInputChange(val, 1)
        } else {
            this.props.onInputChange(0, 0)
        }
    }
    render() {
        let val = this.props.sum;
        return (
            <div className="CalcTable_Input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Зарплата" />
                <input type="text" placeholder={val + ' ₽'} value={(val > 0) ? val + ' ₽' : ''} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Calc extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            value: 0,
            stateless: 0
        }
    }
    onInputChange(value, stateless) {
        console.log(this);
       this.setState({
           value: parseInt(value),
           stateless: stateless
       })
    }
    render() {
        const value = this.state.value;
        return (
            <div className="Calc">
                <h1>Калькулятор</h1>
                <div className="CalcWrapper">
                    <div className="CalcTable">
                        <div className="CalcTable_Wrapper">
                            <div>Заработок</div>
                            <InputGroup sum={value} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="CalcSeparator">&ndash;</div>
                    <div className="CalcTable">
                        <div className="CalcTable_Wrapper">
                            <div>Траты</div>
                            <InputGroup sum={value} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="CalcSeparator">=</div>
                    <div className="CalcSum">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы намеренно отдаете в оба компонента одну и ту же функцию-handler. В такой ситуации логично класть значения не в переменную value, а в массив объектов с результатами. А в функцию onInputChange передавать синтетический id из props. В итоге Ваш state будет выглядеть {values: Array<{id, value, stateless}>} и сможет поддерживать N результатов для N компонентов

Comment: Да, спасибо, реализовал